# $\zeta(e)$ and possible existence of a rational constant.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, infinity, eulers-method

Today I tried to compute $\zeta$(e) but no luck.Here's my approach:-
$$\zeta(e)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^e$$= $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(2n)^e$$+$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/(2n+1)^e$$
After that I have no idea what to do.If there exists a rational constant then what is it? and if not what is the proof?

Here I am not trying to find an approximation or a series representation.**Some might say that I should use Taylor series but I don't think so that it will help**.
Any insights?

Comment: I'd be more surprised if there is a known meaningful closed form for it, considering we don't have one for $\zeta(3)$ and are somewhat lucky to know it's irrational in the first place (but not necessarily transcendental).

Comment: So it's impossible

Comment: Well, we don't know if it is possible, but if you were able to compute it, it would likely require new mathematics, not this elementary effort.

Comment: Yeah it's way too elementary but sometimes elementary methods are much more efficient than complex methods.

Comment: I'd bet my house that no one here can help you determine whether it's rational (for instance). I also think that many here, if they are honest, would advise that working on this is a waste of time. No rudeness intended, but it's one of billions of quite random questions that one might ask, that I can't imagine justifying the interest for.